# Tkinter how to select part of a combobox data programmatically, in Python

Tags: tkinter

Is there a way to select only part of a combobox. I know how to get the selection, I use...

```
widget.index("sel.first"), widget.index("sel.last")
```

I save the state of my app when it's close and want to restore it to the way it was when it's started again. This includes anything that was selected when closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the combobox documentation, the combobox supports many of the ttk.Entry methods, including the methods for getting and setting the selection.

Example:

```
widget.selection_range(2,4)
```

Comment: Thank you, I looked at the docs and didn't see that command. Where are the docs for this. I looked at... https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#combobox

Comment: @DanielHuckson: near the top of what you linked to it says _"Besides the methods inherited from Widget: ..., and the following inherited from Entry: ...Entry.selection()"_.  It's also mentioned in the help that comes with ttk (eg: `help(ttk.Combobox)`).

Comment: Thanks again, I ended up finding the docs for it here... https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm